# Python Tornado handler behavior

Tags: python, tornado

I am playing with Python Tornado and have what should be a very basic question.

As I understand the code snippet below invoking either *localhost:3000* or *localhost:3000/register* should direct me to register.html but for whatever reason *localhost:3000* successfully takes me to the page where *localhost:3000/register* produces a 404. What subtlety am I overlooking?

Thanks.

```
class RegisterHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

def post(self):
    self.render("register.html")

-------------------------------

options.parse_command_line()
app = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r'/',         RegisterHandler),
        (r'/register', RegisterHandler),
    ],
    debug=True
)
app.listen(options.port)
logging.info("app started, visit http://localhost:%s" % options.port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code on my machine with the latest Tornado and it works as you expect.

Comment: This means my problems lie elsewhere. This was helpful.

Comment: For future people I want to just say that this was complete and total PEBCAK error. The code I thought I was running was out of sync with my templates.